# Removing an ArrayList's elements

Tags: java, methods, for-loop, arraylist

I am new to using `ArrayList`'s in java.  I have several lists and want to write a method for removing a list with its elements. Here is what I have so far:

```
public void delete(double value){
    list.remove(value);
}
```

After that I want get the output:

```
public ArrayList<Double> getlist(){
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is; what do you mean by "removing a list"? Remove a list from what?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you be more specific.

Comment: I have several lists. I wanna method for removing a list  if it is met a condition

Comment: What is the question? You say you want to remove a list, but the method you've implemented appears to remove a double _from_ a list.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us some code that demonstrates that you have several lists.  The code you've shared tells us nothing about your problem.

Comment: I am trying to remove the whole list not the values inside the list

Comment: Also the remove method from ArrayList receives the index of the list element to be removed not the value, the above code should not compile

Comment: I think the OP just wants to tell the GC that the list can be destroyed. If I'm not mistaken he moved in from C++ and wants to call `delete some_pointer`. Is that the case Dan? It looks to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets assume you have a few `ArrayLists` like this...

```
ArrayList list1;
ArrayList list2;
ArrayList list3;
```

Are you saying that, depending on a given value, you want to remove one of these lists? So something like this...

```
public void deleteList(ArrayList listToRemove){
    listToRemove = null;
}

public void chooseListToRemove(int listNumber){
    if (listNumber == 1){
        deleteList(list1);
    }
    else if (listNumber == 2){
        deleteList(list2);
    }
    else if (listNumber == 3){
        deleteList(list3);
    }
}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Otherwise, are you saying you have a single `ArrayList` that contains many other lists...

```
ArrayList allLists;
allLists.add(new ArrayList());
allLists.add(new ArrayList());
allLists.add(new ArrayList());
```

And you want to remove one of these lists like this...

```
public void deleteList(int listNumber){
    allLists.remove(listNumber);
}
```

So that if you started with 3 lists in `allLists` and then removed 1 of them, you could ask `allLists.size()` and it would tell you that there are only 2 lists left?

If its neither of these, you'll really need to explain your question better so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From List interface:

Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

```
boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c);
```